# Return Eloquent Relationship Dependent on Value of Field in Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Say I have a Model, and I want to return a relationship, but it depends on a value of an attribute of the model. I tried this in my model:

```
public function paymentType(){
    if($this->type > 1) return $this->hasOne(PaymentType::class, 'type', 'type');
    if($this->type == 1) return $this->hasOne(PaymentType::class, 'payment_type', 'pay_type');
}
```

When I have an instance of the model, I can call this relationship fine, however when I try to eager load, and call `with('paymentType')`, I get the exception `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null`

Comment: Do you have a `with()` call somewhere in a query that uses the `paymentType()` relation?

Comment: Yes, I should have noted in my question, when I have an instance of the model, the method works fine. However, when I try wot eager load the relationship `->with('paymentType)` I get the exception.
Fixed in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that your issue with eager loading arises because the models are not yet populated with values. Trying to check for a model's type with `$this->type` goes against the nature of eager loading.

You options are to:

A) Use lazy loading so that `type` is populated in the model before you call the relationship, or

B) [Use eager loading constraints](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)